# Migration from Postgres to MySQL using MySQL Workbench (Error in Reverse Engineering catalog. A task has failed while execution)

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration, mysql-workbench

When I am trying to migrate database from Postgres to Mysql, I am facing an error in the Reverse engineering source step in which the log shows

```
Starting...
Connect to source DBMS...
- Connecting...
Connect to source DBMS done
Reverse engineer selected schemas....
Reverse engineering acl, audit, crm, doc, dunning, finance, mediation, mst, policy, public, railwire, reports, srv, unifyepg from railtel
- Reverse engineering catalog information
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/db_postgresql_re_grt.py", line 350, in reverseEngineer
    return PostgresqlReverseEngineering.reverseEngineer(connection, catalog_name, schemata_list, context)
  File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/db_generic_re_grt.py", line 237, in reverseEngineer
    catalog = cls.reverseEngineerCatalog(connection, catalog_name)
  File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/db_generic_re_grt.py", line 397, in reverseEngineerCatalog
    cls.reverseEngineerSequences(connection, schema)
  File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/db_postgresql_re_grt.py", line 76, in reverseEngineerSequences
    min_value, max_value, start_value, increment_by, last_value, is_cycled, ncache = cls.execute_query(connection, seq_details_query % (schema.name, seq_name)).fetchone()
  File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/db_generic_re_grt.py", line 76, in execute_query
    return cls.get_connection(connection_object).cursor().execute(query, *args, **kwargs)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42703', '[42703] ERROR: column "min_value" does not exist;\nError while executing the query (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/mysql-workbench/libraries/workbench/wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 192, in thread_work
    self.func()
  File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/migration_schema_selection.py", line 175, in task_reveng
    self.main.plan.migrationSource.reverseEngineer()
  File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/migration.py", line 369, in reverseEngineer
    self.state.sourceCatalog = self._rev_eng_module.reverseEngineer(self.connection, self.selectedCatalogName, self.selectedSchemataNames, self.state.applicationData)
SystemError: ProgrammingError("('42703', '[42703] ERROR: column "min_value" does not exist;\nError while executing the query (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')"): error calling Python module function DbPostgresqlRE.reverseEngineer
ERROR: Reverse engineer selected schemas: ProgrammingError("('42703', '[42703] ERROR: column "min_value" does not exist;\nError while executing the query (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')"): error calling Python module function DbPostgresqlRE.reverseEngineer
Failed
```

Same error can be seen when i migrate the complete Postgres database or only a single schema. So what would be the reason for it?